# Como fazer estimativas de tempo de desenvolvimento?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, metodologia-ágil

Estou começando a tentar usar o Kanban na prática. No caso, eu trabaho sozinho, então estou tentando buscar essa resposta em um contexto no qual não há equipe disponível, muito menos processos mais formais encontrados em empresas maiores.

Ao utilizar metodologias ágeis é comum tentar fazer estimativas. Uma técnica que recentemente conheci é utilizar pomodoros e a sequencia de Fibonacci. Com essa técnica estimamos o tempo em pomodoros: um pomodoro se refere a 25 minutos de trabalho e 5 minutos de descanso. Para estimar uma tarefa usamos os números da sequência de Fibonacci. Uma tarefa pode ser estimada em 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21... pomodoros e assim por diante.

O problema que eu vejo é: nesse caso temos uma unidade de tempo específica para usar e temos uma sequência de "números permitidos" para essa unidade de tempo a nossa disposição.

De qualquer forma, é necessário ainda olhar para cada tarefa e dizer: essa tarefa requer X unidades de tempo.

Isso parece ser realmente muito complicado por vários fatores:

- Certas vezes pode se tratar de algo que nunca fizemos antes e não temos ideia de quanto tempo aquilo demora,
- As vezes achamos que algo é fácil e rápido e no fim não era tão simples quanto pensávamos
- Podem ocorrer imprevistos e fazer demorar mais. Isso se não aparecer uma complicação tão grande no meio do caminho que acabe "emperrando" o desenvolvimento

Esses são só alguns fatores que eu pensei que complicam isso. Para mim, que estou começando agora com as metodologias ágeis em prática mesmo, eu realmente não consigo ter a menor ideia de como atribuir X unidades de tempo para cada tarefa.

Na teoria parece simples, na prática não é tão simples assim. Dessa forma, como fazer estimativas de forma correta ao utilizar metodologias ágeis? Como contornar essas complicações que eu citei? Qual é a "métrica" usada para atribuir um certo número de unidades de tempo a uma tarefa?

Comment: super interessante o levantamento, mas veja : Estimativa, é algo inexato, para situações onde vão ocorrer fatores imprevisíveis, vc levantou pontos que reforçam esta afirmação, ex:"algo que nunca fizemos antes e não temos ideia de quanto tempo aquilo demora"... Acredito que as métricas derivam de eventos já realizados... Esse é só um ponto que observei. O Kanban, ao meu ver, não interfere diretamente em suas questões, porém algo que poderia auxiliar seria o  https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciclo_PDCA , mas vamos aguardar outras sugestões, muito me interessa a solução para as questões

Comment: Eu tenho usado APF (Análise de ponto de função). É um pouco complexo para entender pois tem que sair da cabeça o desenvolvimento em si, mas temos conseguido estimar com uma taxa minima de erro. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_de_pontos_de_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: o maior problema de desenvolver software é estimar, vivo na pele esse dilema todo dia +1 pela curiosidade.

Comment: Leonardo, seu questionamento é muito bom. Não sou "expert" no assunto, mas tenho muito interesse. Como você está iniciando e não tem uma equipe ainda isso tende a ser mais complicado, mas a minha dica é estimar quanto você levaria para implementar um formulário simples. Digamos que este formulário (testado, validado) equivala a 3 em sua escala (não vamos pensar em horas agora, certo?), então a cada nova funcionalidade que tenhas que estimar tente pensar assim "isso equivale a quantos formulários simples?". É isso que aplico, e por sinal aprendi com outras pessoas. Futuramente caso você tenha u

Comment: Cara, onde você viu essa locuragem de associar pomodoro com fibonacci?? Se fibonacci em estimativa fosse multiplicador de um tempo exato, não seria muito mais fácil simplesmente apontar o tempo exato em horas? Pomodoro, por sua vez, é uma técnica para manter o foco e não tem nada a ver com estimativas. E Kanban, por sua vez, é um método para gestão de mudanças em processos, não um método de desenvolvimento de software, muito menos trabalhando sozinho. Resposta para você que trabalha sozinho: não desperdice muita energia fazendo estimativas - use esta energia para fazer software.

Comment: @Caffé, eu vi em um curso sobre metodologias ágeis. Mas na verdade pode ser que o jeito que eu escrevi na pergunta que ficou estranho. Eu não supus uma conexão direta. O que eu vi foi que fibonacci é usado para dizer os valores possíveis de unidades de tempo. Já pomodoro eu vi que é uma técnica para manter o foco, mas ele fornece "unidades de tempo", medir o tempo em pomodoros. Mas não que as duas coisas estejam associadas. O que eu entendi é que da pra aplicar as duas coisas de forma conjunta, medindo o tempo em pomodoros e não em horas.

Comment: @Leonardo Entendi. Mas não é o caso de aplicá-las conjuntamente não. São coisas bem distintas. A idéia de usar sequência fibonacci é justamente não vincular a estimativa a um tempo exato, mas sim ao grau de complexidade da tarefa/requisito, e sem ignorar que algo complexo nem sempre demora mais do que algo simples. Grosseiramente falando, é mais uma, dentre tantas, técnicas de "chutar uma estimativa". Parece haver bastante gente interessada e a pergunta não foi fechada. Vou tentar dar uma resposta útil. (Mais tarde).

Comment: Dica *metafórica* pra vida: você vai precisar de **uma régua** e de **uma equipe**. A régua será utilizada pra medir, claro. Não importa a régua que utilizar ou o sistema de medidas dela (metros, jardas, etc), **use sempre a mesma régua** (senão suas estimativas jamais serão úteis). O time será utilizado para construir, claro, mas também para definir a produtividade. Certos times vão levar mais tempo, outros menos tempo, para produzir **1 unidade de tamanho** da sua régua. Normal. Saiba disso. Como? **Chute, erre, armazene e refine**. Na próxima vez a estimativa vai ser mais acertada.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, eu poderia postar aqui, mas acho que fica ruim de ler, quando tem bastante teoria. Uma das técnicas utilizadas é Pontos por Função, dê uma pesquisada é bem simples e se aproxima muito do esperado. Basicamente você vai encontrar as funções do software e analisar a quantidade de campos na tabela, as interfaces etc...

Answer (score 15):

**Como fazer estimativas ?**

De acordo com diversos especialista,há duas maneiras de se estimar um desenvolvimento de um projeto software,eis as duas :

> 1-) Por Analogia – As estimativas de tamanho do projeto atual são baseadas em estimativas já desenvolvidas em projetos similares ou as chamadas bases históricas de outros projetos ou;
>
> 2- ) desenvolvendo as técnica de medições das características do produto e usando uma metodologia e algoritmo para converter a medição em uma estimativa de tamanho.

**Metodologias básicas**

Bom no seu caso,lhe aconselho a dar uma olhada [neste artigo](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html) e [neste artigo](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/03/estimating-software-development.html) para saber melhor como projetar suas próprias estimativas em base dos seus trabalhos e quanto tempo você demora para fazer uma certa tarefa.

Um método interessante seria você usar em base o `Planning Poker`,que já foi citado,que é um jogo de consenso usado principalmente para estimar o esforço ou tamanho relativo as metas de desenvolvimento de um software.Te aconselho a dar uma olhada [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_poker) para saber mais sobre o assunto e também a dar uma olhada [aqui](https://www.pointingpoker.com/) para poder criar online seu próprio `Planning Poker`.

O que também pode lhe ajudar a fazer certas estimativas de tempo de desenvolvimento é criar um `Diagrama de Gantt`.

> O diagrama de Gantt é um gráfico usado para ilustrar o avanço das diferentes etapas de um projeto. Os intervalos de tempo representando o início e fim de cada fase aparecem como barras coloridas sobre o eixo horizontal do gráfico.

Exemplo de `Diagrama de Gantt` :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Metodologias complexas**

Existem várias metodologias para se criar estimativas de tempo de desenvolvimento de software,as quais são :

**COCOMO ( Constructive Cost Model) [COCOMOII]**

> Modelo desenvolvido para estimar o esforço de desenvolvimento, prazos e tamanho da equipe para projetos de software. Utiliza equações desenvolvidas por Boehm (BARRY,1981) para prever o número de programadores-mês e o tempo de desenvolvimento; podem ser calculados usando medidas de linhas de código ou Pontos de Função. Devem ser realizados ajustes nas equações a fim de representar as influências sobre os atributos , hardware e software durante o ciclo de vida do projeto. Uma desvantagem desta técnica é que os coeficientes da métrica (a,b,c,d) não são aplicáveis a tamanho ou seja a produtividade é diferente, o que torna difícil realizar comparações.

**Linhas de Código – (LOC)**

> A técnica de mensuração por linhas de código é uma das mais antigas medidas de tamanho de projeto de desenvolvimento de software. Ela consiste na contagem da quantidade de número de linhas de código de um programa de software. Além de ser muito simples é também muito fácil automatizar sua implementação , mas, apresenta algumas desvantagens dentre as quais citamos: a dependência da linguagem de software e do desenvolvedor (PRESSMAN,1995); ausência de padrão de contagem e o fato de somente poder ser aplicada na fase de codificação.

**Metricas de Hasltead**

> É um conjunto de métricas proposto por Maurice Halstead
> (HASLTEAD,1977). O princípio desse método está na análise e quantificação de operando e operadores e no conceito de que a partir do conhecimento das medidas, consegue-se quantificar os vocábulos e a extensão do algoritmo do estudo.

**Puttnam´s Slim Model (PUTMAN,1978)**

> É um modelo de estimativa que busca medir esforço e prazo através da dinâmica de múltiplas variáveis que pressupõe distribuição de
> esforços específicos ao longo da existência de um projeto de software. Relaciona o número de linhas de código ao tempo e esforço de desenvolvimento. Uma desvantagem da técnica é sua vinculação a linguagem usada e a exigência de certo tempo para obter-se valores reais para os parâmetros da fórmula.

**Delphi**

> É uma técnica que se resume à consulta de especialistas de determinada área, em determinada linguagem e/ou determinado assunto para que, usando sua experiência e entendimento do projeto proposto, façam estimativas devidas. Devem ser feitas várias estimativas do mesmo projeto, pois é comum que elas carreguem influências e tendências dos especialistas. É um método empírico, baseado em experiências profissionais que podem ser subjetivas.(Boehm,1981)

**PSP – Personal Software Process – (HUMPHREY,1995)**

> É uma técnica derivada do SEI-CMM (Software Engineering Institute – Capability Matutiry Model) que foi
> desenvolvida com a função de capacitar , melhorar e otimizar o processo individual de trabalho. A técnica divide-se em sete etapas, sendo que nas etapas PSP0, PSP0.1 e PSP1
> estima-se o tamanho e o tempo necessário para o desenvolvimento do produto.

**PCU – Pontos por Caso de Uso**

> Foram criados por Gustav Karner em 1993 como uma adaptação específica dos Pontos de Função para medir o tamanho de projetos de software orientados a objeto. Explora o modelo e descrição do caso de uso, substituindo algumas características técnicas proposta pelos Pontos de Função. É um método simples e de fácil utilização mas ainda esta em fase de pesquisas e não existem regras de contagem padronizadas. Têm se estudado a aplicação em conjunto da PCU e APF tentando explorar a relação entre elas existente.(EDMÉIA,2004)

**Análise por Pontos de Função (ALBRECHT,1983)**

> Busca medir a complexidade do produto pela quantificação de funcionalidade expressa pela visão que o usuário tem do mesmo. O modelo mede o que é o sistema , o seu tamanho funcional e não como este será, além de medir a relação do sistema com usuários e outro sistemas. È independente da tecnologia usada e mede uma aplicação pelas funções desempenhadas para/e por solicitação do usuário final.; podendo também ser usada em estimativas.

**Conclusão**

A estimativa de tamanho de um projeto de software é uma atividade crítica pois tem um impacto tanto na solução técnica apresentada como no gerenciamento do projeto de software devendo ser efetuada não somente no início do projeto mas durante o ciclo de vida do projeto. As técnicas apresentadas acima são apenas algumas dentre as muitas existentes, sendo que cada uma abrange uma determinada área; não existe uma métrica que completa o estudo por si só, desta forma, recomenda-se que seja utilizada a técnica mais adequada para medir projeto de software ou a utilização de mais de uma técnica em conjunto. Dentre as técnicas descritas, a mais popular atualmente é a técnica de Análise por Pontos de Função. Esta técnica é respaldada pelo IFPUG (International Function Point Users Group), que é responsável, entre outros, pela elaboração e divulgação de um manual de práticas de contagem (CPM – Counting Practices Manual), além de manter um programa de certificação de profissionais especializados em aplicar a técnica APF. A Análise de Pontos de Função (APF) é uma das métricas de estimativa de tamanho mais sedimentadas no mercado e que proporciona resultados cada vez mais precisos à medida que artefatos da fase de análise e projeto são gerados.

**Bibliografias**

> COCOMO – Constructive Cost Model. Disponível em: http://sunset.usc.edu/research/COCOMOII/
>
> DEMARCO, TOM. Controle de Projetos de Software. 9.ed. Rio de Janeiro: Editora Campus, 1991.
>
> VAZQUEZ, Carlos Eduardo, SIMÕES, Guilherme Siqueira, ALBERT, Renato Machado – ANÁLISE DE PONTOS DE FUNÇÃO, Medição, Estimativas e Gerenciamento de Projetos de Software, 13.ed. São Paulo: Editora Érica, 2013.
>
> MACORATTI, José Carlos – Estimativas de tamanho de software e APF. Disponível em: : http://www.macoratti.net/net_est1.htm

Comment: Embora esta resposta contenha basicamente texto copiado de outros sites, eu acho que este é um assunto importante. Favor observar que 3 dos 8 métodos listados **não são de estimativa** mas sim de medição do tamanho do software, a ser feita **depois que o software já existe** e não antes. Das outras, algumas não contém sequer a mais superficial explicação, e uma delas (a Delphi) é um método de adivinhação e não de medição. Favor notar também que o Gráfico de Gantt não tem nada a ver com estimativa de software, ele serve para monitorar os desvios entre previsto e executado de tarefas encadeadas.

Comment: @Caffé Sim,suas observações são interessantes mesmo,mas eu sei que o Diagrama de Gantt não tem a ver com estimativa,mas ele pode também ajudar a organizar tarefas em depois saber como estimar mais ou menos quanto tempo poderá demorar para terminar uma certa tarefa e consequentemente pode servir para ajudar a criar estimativas de tempo de um software.

Answer (score 12):

Existem basicamente **dois métodos** de se fazer estimativa de custo de desenvolvimento de software:

a) **Adivinhar** quanto vai custar.

b) **Medir** quanto vai custar.

Todos os métodos de estimativa são derivados destas duas maneiras básicas aí.

Os adeptos do **método a** estão sempre tentando aprimorar suas técnicas de adivinhação e os adeptos do **método b** estão sempre tentando aprimorar suas técnicas de medição.

## a) Estimativa por medição

É o jeito mais antigo e tradicional de se estimar software.

Umas das técnicas mais populares deste método é a contagem de pontos por função, que funciona mais ou menos assim:

- Levanta-se os requisitos
- Desenha-se os casos de uso com base nos requisitos
- Detalha-se os casos de uso nas funções que o compõem (há um range de tipos de função previamente estabelecido)
- Soma-se os pontos de todas as funções (cada tipo de função tem uma quantidade de pontos previamente estabelecida)
- Multiplica-se o total de pontos por uma unidade de valor (tempo, dinheiro...)
- Aplica-se uma gordura.

<sub>Pode haver mais fatores influenciando a previsão de custo ou de preço do projeto (custo de gerência, risco, valor agregado, etc.), mas estes outros fatores estarão presentes conforme a natureza e ambiente do projeto e independentemente do método de estimativa escolhido.</sub>

O valor de cada ponto de função é uma decisão gerencial que se baseia em experiências prévias (próprias ou de mercado) e em outros interesses de marketing.

Este é um método incrivelmente eficaz.

É difícil errar a estimativa porque a medição é feita sobre documentos muito detalhados de tudo que será implementado. Cada função é um recurso de software bem elementar, como uma das letras do CRUD, se o objeto é uma entidade ou um relacionamento, etc. E é fácil acertar o tamanho do esforço para fazer uma implementação tão pequena.

O problema é que contar tudo que será feito exige que você saiba de antemão tudo que será feito. Ou seja, você tem que fazer um bom **investimento em entendimento e detalhamento do escopo ainda antes de começar a fazer software**.

Em projetos deste tipo, é natural esta fase **demorar meses** e custar o trabalho de vários consultores, comerciais e técnicos, que geralmente são os mais experientes da organização (os mais caros) pois a premissa é que esta fase seja concluída com muita qualidade.

É normal que este esforço tenha **outras relevâncias** no projeto além da estimativa, como por exemplo confiar na **abrangente documentação** produzida nesta fase para garantir que será desenvolvido o software certo, contar com a documentação como um suporte para manutenções futuras, ou receber uma assinatura do cliente nesta documentação (um **contrato**) e se blindar **contra mudanças** para garantir a margem ou o prazo.

Estas outras relevâncias da documentação trazem mais alguns contras a este método: você tem que desenhar todo o sistema antes de aprender todo o necessário sobre ele, pois o aprendizado, tando do cliente quanto do time, acontece durante a implementação do projeto e depois que o cliente começa a enxergar o software que é entregue.

Se você dificulta as mudanças, o cliente pode estar perdendo oportunidade de obter mais valor deste projeto. E se você se abre às mudanças, você está jogando fora o investimento que fez lá no começo quando tentou prever tudo que seria feito e todo o custo.

## b) Estimativa por adivinhação

Este é o método preferido dos processos **Ágeis**, já que eles valorizam mais o **software funcionando**, cedo, do que documentação abrangente; mais **colaboração** com o cliente do que a negociação de contratos; são **abertos à mudança** e inclusive a encorajam; acreditam que a melhor **arquitetura e design emergem** em vez de serem previamente definidos; etc.

Como a idéia aqui é justamente permitir a mudança, não faz sentido investir muito em fechar um escopo, então geralmente constrói-se uma visão macro do projeto e uma estimativa aproximada, que só pode ser adivinhada já que não há o que medir pois ainda não se sabe exatamente o que será feito.

Existem vários métodos de adivinhação. Para definir um custo geral do projeto antes de começa-lo, é comum definir as **capacidades ou features**, que são os mega requisitos do projeto, adivinhar quanto vai custar cada uma e somar.

**"Adivinhar"** é um termo correto pois é admitido pelo projeto que o futuro é incerto, é admitido que não há ainda conhecimento profundo sobre cada feature ou capacidade para ter certeza de todo o trabalho que será necessário, e não há intenção de se adquirir adiantamente este conhecimento - dá-se preferência por começar a entregar software cedo e aprender com isso.

Todas as estimativas são baseadas em experiências prévias, e são difíceis de acertar com precisão pois são feita sobre um conhecimento macro e não detalhado do trabalho que será empregado.

Ainda assim em tese você pode entregar as capacidades previstas dentro do orçamento pois enquanto partes do software são feitas e apresentadas para o cliente, o aprendizado aumenta e permite deixar de executar trabalho que antes parecia necessário.

O contrário também pode acontecer e você identificar que errou muito feio na adivinhação, e que será impossível entregar as capacidades pelo custo previsto. Neste caso assume-se o novo custo ou cancela-se cedo o projeto antes de o prejuízo ser grande demais.

Veja que no outro método você também pode errar feio - não a estimativa de custo mas sim a previsão do que deveria ser implementado pois previu isso sem contar com o conhecimento que adquire-se durante o projeto. Neste caso, quando o projeto for cancelado, todo o custo daquela fase inicial soma-se ao prejuízo. Ou pior: como você já "sabia" tudo que precisava fazer e não queria mesmo que viessem mudanças, você não entregou o software em partes mas sim deixou tudo pro final - ou seja: risco de prejuízo total.

### Adivinhações durante o projeto

Bem, até aqui eu só falei sobre a adivinhação que acontece no começo do projeto. Mas e durante o projeto, como são estimadas as tarefas (pequenos requisitos que vão constituir o mega requisito - a tal da capacidade/feature)?

Aqui acontece o mesmo tipo de adivinhação baseado em conhecimento empírico. Os métodos Ágeis de maneira geral desencorajam a estimativa em horas, pois admitem que não se pode prever com tal nível de precisão quanto vai custar mesmo um requisito pequeno.

Então inventou-se **story points** que são uma estimativa de esforço ou de tamanho ou de complexidade da tarefa, mas não estão diretamente relacionadas a custo em horas. A idéia é que com o tempo aprenda-se quantos pontos se pode fazer num período e que isso ajude a estimar as tarefas que poderão ser completadas, conforme sua quantidade de pontos, num período seguinte de igual tamanho.

Num esforço de desvincular ainda mais as estimativas Ágeis das estimativas em horas, utiliza-se escalas fibonacci ou os tamanhos "P", "M" e "G" (tipo tamanhos de camiseta) para desestimular a associação com horas (a associação imediata fica mais difícil pois o cálculo de conversão é mais difícil ou abstrato).

Para buscar uma adivinhação mais promissora, existe ainda o **planning poker**, que conta com a experiência de vários profissionais ao mesmo tempo para evitar desvios grandes demais para mais ou para menos. Você pode ler como funciona o planning poker por aí ou fazer uma pergunta específica pois só isso já dá alguns parágrafos.

### Abaixo as adivinhações

Por fim, a última moda no universo Ágil é buscar alternativas para que não seja preciso sequer tentar adivinhar estimativas.

O raciocínio é o seguinte: se medir o projeto (aqui apresentado como "método a") não atende bem o cliente e se não somos tão bons em adivinhar ("método b"), que tal esquecer essa parada de estimar?

O nome deste movimento é **#NoEstimates** e a idéia, é claro, não é simplesmente deixar de estimar software, mas sim buscar alternativas a isso. Tipo "não conseguimos estimar, então o que podemos fazer em vez disso para garantir a relação custo/valor/prazo para o cliente?".

Considera-se ainda que embora o cliente precise saber quanto vai gastar e quanto tempo vai levar, a estimativa em si não tem valor para ele, e o que não tem valor, segundo o pensamento lean, deveria ser eliminado do processo (ok, ok, esta é outra história, ainda mais longa, então fica pra outra hora).

## Estimativas para quem?

Como eu comentei de leve, questiona-se muito o valor das estimativas para o cliente.

De algum modo ele precisa saber quanto vai custar e quando fica pronto, ok. Segundo os métodos Ágeis, isso pode ser resolvido com macro estimativa de capacidades/features, entregas interativas e escopo aberto.

E quanto vai custar cada tarefa? Quanto vai custar cada um daqueles 10 pequenos requisitos que você pretende desenvolver nas próximas duas semanas? Será que você precisa mesmo calcular isso? Vai vender essa medição pra quem? Quem vai pagar por este esforço? Qual o valor em pregar um número fibonacci em cada post-it do quadro?

Por isso, se você estiver trabalhando sozinho ou se o seu projeto permitir, se não houver um gerente te cobrando isso, procure libertar-se das estimativas de curto prazo pois o seu valor real para o projeto até agora não foi demonstrado.

## Observações finais

Conforme já conversamos nos comentários, a relação entre fibonacci e pomodoro não existe.

Pomodoro é uma técnica para manter o foco.

E usar números da sequência fibonacci nas estimativas é justamente um esforço de desvincular as estimativas do custo em horas.

## Uma referência para dar valor à resposta

Ron Jeffries, um dos caras que assinou o Manifesto Ágil, que criou o Extreme Programing e que ajudou a inventar essas coisas de *"story points"* e "velocidade do time", é engajado no movimento **#NoEstimates**. Inclusive ele já pediu desculpas por ter inventado esse negócio de estimar em pontos. Segue:

> "Existe um número de idéias sobre como estimar usando alguma outra coisa que não tempo [horas]. Pontos, Gummi Bears, números Fibonacci, tamanhos de camiseta. Eles foram originalmente inventados para obscurecer o aspecto de tempo, de modo que a gerência não seria tentada a mal utilizar as estimativas. (Eu sei: eu estava lá quando eles foram inventados. **Na verdade eu devo ter inventado os Pontos. Se eu inventei, me desculpe agora.**)"

Veja este pedido de desculpas e muitas coisas intererssantes em: https://pragprog.com/magazines/2013-02/estimation-is-evil

Comment: Desculpe, mas eu ri ao ler o item "Aplica-se uma gordura". Isso é dizer que se usa o método B, quando na verdade se usa o método A mas com todo o trabalho burocrático do método B. :)

Comment: Pois é, @LuizVieira, seria cômico se não fosse trágico. É claro que não é formalmente chamado de gordura. Formalmente, você *"considera as Características Gerais do Sistema (GSCs) para calcular o Valor do Fator de Ajuste (VAF) e aplicá-lo sobre a Contagem de Pontos de Função Não Ajustada (Unadjusted FP Count) de modo a obter a Contagem de Pontos de Função Ajustada (Adjusted FP Count)"*. Como muitas das GSCs são super subjetivas, você atribui a elas o valor que bem entender de modo a obter a gordura final que desejar.

Comment: Excelente resposta, +1.

Answer (score 6):

Estimação de software é fundamental para qualquer projeto. Estimativas de custo, esforço e prazo são geralmente demandadas por clientes e o gerente do projeto precisa ter uma base para o planejamento e para tomar decisões no decorrer do projeto. A estimação também contribui para um maior entendimento do problema e provê um horizonte para a conclusão do projeto ou da iteração.

O planejamento exige que você assuma um compromisso inicial, mesmo que mais tarde ele venha se mostrar errado. Sempre que forem feitas estimativas deve-se olhar o futuro e aceitar certo grau de incerteza.

> ...nossas técnicas de estimativas são muito mal desenvolvidas. E, mais
>   grave ainda refletem uma suposição um tanto falsa não declara de que
>   tudo sairá  bem...como não temos certeza sobre nossas estimativas,
>   gerentes de softwares mutias vezes não tem a firmeza necessária para
>   fazer as pessoas esperar por um bom produto (Brooks)

Uma estimativa nada mais é do que uma estimativa. Processos matemáticos podem dar a falsa impressão de veracidade, mas a base é subjetividade com base em uma definição abstrata do sistema.

> Estimar é prover uma visão do projeto clara o suficiente para que a
>   gerência possa tomar boas decisões de como gerenciar o projeto para
>   que o mesmo atinja seus objetivos (McConnell)

Incerteza na estimativa.
Basicamente, conheça o que tem que ser feito, de outra maneira sua estimativa vai ser provavelmente errada.

[image: Cone da Incerteza]

No início do projeto a incerteza atinge seu ápice, mas diminui na medida em que as tarefas são concluídas.
Quanto mais cedo ocorrer a estimação, piores serão as estimativas. A estimação antecipada de todo o software tende a gerar estimativas piores do que em casos onde elas são feitas em fases posteriores do projeto.

Embora muitas vezes seja necessário estimar todo o software, é importante refazer a estimação quando se deseja obter uma posição atualizada sobre o estágio de desenvolvimento.
O software é mutável, os requisitos mudam ao longo do tempo.

**Algumas Tecnicas e modelos de estimação:**

**Planning Poker**

Alguns processos ágeis, como o Scrum, encaram o projeto de software como um jogo. Nessa linha, alguns autores consideram a melhor forma de estimar uma espécie de poker com as histórias de usuário do backlog (Cohn, 2006, p. 55).
No Planning Poker, todos os membros da equipe de desenvolvimento se reúnem. Primeiramente, cada membro recebe cartas. Cada carta contém um valor da escala de story point definida para o projeto. Para cada história de usuário, os membros escolhem secretamente a carta com o valor que consideram ser o tamanho daquela história. Então, todos mostram suas cartas ao mesmo tempo. Quando há consenso, a estimativa seria confiável. Se um ou mais valores forem discrepantes, os membros discutem entre si o motivo porque a história de usuário seria mais ou menos complexa. Após entrarem num consenso, uma nova rodada de cartas é realizada. Isso é feito até que todos estejam de acordo com a estimativa.
Os “agilistas” afirmam que esta técnica tem funcionado bem pelos seguintes motivos (Cohn, 2006, p. 59):

•   aqueles que sabem como fazer o trabalho são os que fazem as estimativas;

•   o diálogo faz com que os estimadores tenham que justificar suas estimativas, portanto eles pensam bem no que estão fazendo;

•   a discussão em grupo, segundo alguns estudos, levam a melhores estimativas.

O Planning Poker geralmente é feito de forma mais intensa, porém menos detalhada, no início do projeto, de modo a gerar as estimativas iniciais necessárias para o planejamento geral e o número de iterações.
No início de cada iteração, sugere-se levar algo em torno de uma hora para detalhar as estimativas das histórias de usuário que serão implementadas, as quais, que nesse ponto, estão dividias em tarefas. O tempo de estimar varia de acordo com o tamanho da iteração.

**Estimação orientada a objetos**

Sistemas orientados a objetos podem ser estimados através de modelagem orientada a objetos, como a UML (Unified Modeling Language). Atribui-se valores a cada objeto do sistema e, assim, pode-se chegar a uma estimativa geral.
Algumas medidas sugeridas por Pressman (2009, p. 506) são:

•   número de scripts de cenários de interação entre usuário e o sistema;

•   número de classes importantes e independentes do sistema;

•   número de classes de apoio não relacionadas ao domínio (banco de dados, interface com usuário);

•   número de classes de apoio relacionadas ao domínio;

•   número de subsistemas.

**Estimação orientada a casos de uso**

É possível utilizar casos de uso para estimar um software. As estimativas de cada caso de uso possibilitariam planejar o projeto com um todo.

Entretanto, como casos de uso são muito abstratos e pessoas diferentes trabalham em diversos níveis de abstração. Não há parâmetros para definir uma medida padrão para o esforço necessário para implementar um dado caso de uso (Pressman, 2009, p. 507). Em decorrência disso, a estimação com casos de uso não é recomendada, sendo pouco utilizada.

Você pode se aprofundar muito mais nesse universo, recomendo:

[O blog State of the art](http://luizricardo.org/) (muita coisa foi tirada de la)

Engenharia de Software - 8ª Edição

Mythical Man Month

Scrum Em ação
....

Answer (score 6):

Só não dou -1 a sua pergunta porque ela vale milhares de dólares para a indústria de software :-) e certamente as respostas que você leu acima são compilações do que se ensina nas Universidades nas disciplinas de Engenharia de Software. Mas agora, vou tirar meu chapéu de professor e colocar o de profissional para responder. Usar a minha própria experiência para responder e não citações daquilo que não uso mais e um dia deu certo, mas hoje para meus projetos e perfis de clientes não funcionam mais.

Se esse assunto fosse fácil não seriam necessários tantos livros sobre a Engenharia de Software que não é Engenharia (tal como conhecemos). Da mesma forma como não gosto de chamar de método aquilo que não tem comportamento bem definido e previsível e a possibilidade de ter sempre os mesmos resultados se aplicado em certas condições. Como diz Fred. Brooks: "não existe a bala de prata". Porém uma coisa que gosto muito de defender é o famoso triângulo do PMI: prazo, custo e esforço que são variáveis fortemente acopladas aos requisitos. Simples e fácil de entender: mexeu nos requisitos, afetará uma ou mais dessas variáveis. Exemplo: Encurtou o prazo vai ter que cortar requisitos. Aumentou escopo? Esticará o prazo por conta de esforço (e aí vem o erro clássico: aumento o time não tenho problemas com prazo - horda mongólica).

Se você for matemático de formação ou conheça profundamente os métodos de programação linear tal como o Simplex, entenderia que, para problemas complexos, existem possíveis soluções para se chegar ao que se chama de solução ótima (não disse correta). Lhe garanto, não existe nenhum método único completo capaz de aferir com certeza o que você quer, porque são ideias, não métodos formais. Trabalham com interpretação de requisitos.

Se você for usar uma estimativa para aplicar um preço ao seu trabalho, afirmo, esqueça. Extremamente falível porque estimam requisitos que não podem ser congelados ao longo do projeto. Eles mudam. Por isso Engenharia de Sfw não é Engenharia. Não adianta. **Precifique pelo esforço de comprometimento**, jamais só considerando o escopo dos requisitos congelados. As grandes fábricas de software misturam abordagens para alinhar o preço do projeto, ajustando de acordo com o prazo / esforço temperando com lucro e análise dos riscos.

Existem empresas vendendo sprints. Acho muito interessante essa abordagem. Não dão um preço final do que não enxergam ou daquilo que pode mudar muito. Parece surreal mas existem clientes maduros o suficiente para entender que este é um modelo interessante e funcional. Para seu caso, para ser pratico estime seu esforço mês o que você consegue entregar nesse mês e venda a sprint tendo como base seu custo/lucro. De uma ideia aproximada de quantidade de sprints e pronto. Esqueça unidade horas, homem/mês (em sua situação) para estimar prazo. Não vou te sugerir uma coisa complexa para ser aplicada em uma fábrica de software por vários profissionais visto que trabalhará sozinho nesse projeto e não tem como ter uma área de Q&A para garantir sucesso (em resumo).

Lembre-se sempre que a qualidade não vem do cumprimento correto dos métodos. Vai muito além disso. Não é porque adotamos um método ou modelo A ou B que teremos uma garantia de qualidade na estimativa, no desenvolvimento ou na entrega.

Espero ter te ajudado a encontrar um ponto de partida.

Comment: Nem todas as respostas são compilações do que se ensina nas universidades. Leia a minha resposta até o fim e observe que a sua aqui vem corroborar com o que já falei lá.

Comment: @Caffé disse que as respostas são, não disse somente a sua. plural e não necessariamente só o seu artigo. Disse isso na minha resposta?

Comment: E eu disse que você disse que era somente a minha? :D

Comment: @Caffé, preciso tomar café kkkkkkkkkk. O que deixaria você feliz, apagar minha resposta? Posso fazer isso sem problema nenhum amigo! :-D

Comment: De maneira nenhuma eu gostaria de ver esta resposta excluída. Acho ela excelente e acho que agrega valor.